# How can I separate a string using JavaScript and assign values to each piece of the String?

Tags: javascript, html, string, split

I have a process that returns 4 different pieces of information, each piece separated by an asterisk(*).  For example, the code will return something like:

Boy*15*Winter*New Years

I want to split this string into individual and assign values to each piece.
So something like this:

```
var gender = Boy
var age = 15
var favoriteSeason = Winter
var favoriteHoliday = New Years
```

But I do not want those variables hard-coded.

Is there a way to do this using javascript?

Comment: Split the string on the asterisk and then map that array to an array that contains the order of data. `['gender', 'age', ...]` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

In ES6, you can do this trivially with [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```
const [gender, age, favoriteSeason, favoriteHoliday] = 'Boy*15*Winter*New Years'.split('*');
```

In ES5, you need to map it a little bit, but can create objects pretty easily:

```
var chunks = 'Boy*15*Winter*New Years'.split('*');
return {
  gender: chunks[0],
  age: chunks[1],
  favoriteSeason: chunks[2],
  favoriteHoliday: chunks[3],
};
```

Either way, the core is [`String.prototype.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) with your separator.

Answer (score 1):

ES2015 version:

```
const [gender, age, favoriteSeason, favoriteHoliday] = yourVar.split('*');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `split()` to break up the string:

```
s = 'Boy*15*Winter*New Years';
a = s.split('*');
gender = s[0];
age = int(s[1])
favoriteSeason = s[2];
favoriteHoliday = s[3];
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var str = "Boy*15*Winter*New Years";

var array = str.split("*");

var gender = array[0];
var age = array[1];
var favoriteSeason = array[2];
var favoriteHoliday = array[3];

console.log(gender, age, favoriteSeason, favoriteHoliday)
```